# MS CRM: Create Address Record Throws Incorrect Attribute Value Type Error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to create an address record but I keep getting the error.

```
The application terminated with an error.
Code: -2147220989
Message: Incorrect attribute value type System.Int32
```

The code is as follows

```
public const int OBJECT_TYPE_CONTACT = 2;



int addressTypeCode = 3; //Primary Address
if (i == 2) addressTypeCode = 1; //Billing Address
if (i == 3) addressTypeCode = 2; //Shipping Address

Entity newAddress = new Entity("customeraddress");
newAddress.Attributes["parentid"] = new EntityReference("contact", existingContact.Id);
newAddress.Attributes["addresstypecode"] = addressTypeCode;
newAddress.Attributes["objecttypecode"] = OBJECT_TYPE_CONTACT;
newAddress.Attributes["line1"] = "temp1";
newAddress.Attributes["line2"] = "temp2";
newAddress.Attributes["line3"] = "temp3";
newAddress.Attributes["city"] = "temp3";
newAddress.Attributes["stateorprovince"] = "temp3";
newAddress.Attributes["postalcode"] = "temp3";
newAddress.Attributes["country"] = "temp3";

Guid id = service.Create(newAddress);
```

The error throws on the line that sets the objecttypecode. I know the error code means "Invalid argument". In the solution 2 refers to the contact so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: The error is actually throwing the line `Guid id = service.Create(newAddress);`. That error will never throw on adding/modifying an item in the `Entity.Attributes` collection because the `Entity` class has no awareness of types. If you use the early bound types (from `CrmSvcUtil.exe`) that will give you type warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change this line:

`newAddress.Attributes["addresstypecode"] = addressTypeCode;`

To:

`newAddress.Attributes["addresstypecode"] = new OptionSetValue(addressTypeCode);`

Because it is an option set the type must be `OptionSetValue`, not `int`.

Comment: Thank you, I should have seen that one